# How to generate date for next 14 days in java?

Tags: java

```
public class datefornext14days {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        for (int i = 1;  i<=14; i++) {
            System.out.println(day);
            c.add(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

While executing the code i got the following error:-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException     at
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar.add(Unknown Source)   at
>   TodayDate.main(TodayDate.java:28)

I wanted my output to be - start from current day and iterate to next 14 days.

Comment: Seems like you mean `c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);` — "add 1 to the `DAY_OF_MONTH` field". Not "add 1 to the field indicated by whatever is the current value of `DAY_OF_MONTH` ". But then you're still just printing out the same value `day` over and over.

Comment: note: if you are using Java >= 8, consider using `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` in `java.time` in place of `Calendar`, which provides "nicer" methods like `plusDays`

Answer (score 0):

remove `c.get(`. The first Parameter of add is the constant for the unit

```
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

For more Informations see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)).

And Output the day in the following way:

```
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

So your code must look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
        System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class datefornext14days {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

   for (int i = 1;  i<=14; i++) {
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DATE));

}

}
```

With this program I got all the dates for next 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you use java 8 then you can do it:

```
LocalDateTime currentLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
    LocalDateTime newLocalDateTime = currentLocalDateTime.plusDays(i);
    System.out.println(newLocalDateTime);
}
```

Also you might change `LocalDateTime` to `LocalDate` if you need only date without time.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9 you can use a very nice `datesUntil` method.

```
LocalDate
  .now()
  .datesUntil(start.plusDays(14))
  .forEach(it -> out.print(" > " + it));
--
> 2017-04-14 > 2017-04-15 > 2017-04-16 > 2017-04-17 > 2017-04-18 > 2017-04-19 > 2017-04-20 > 2017-04-21 > 2017-04-22 > 2017-04-23 > 2017-04-24 > 2017-04-25 > 2017-04-26 > 2017-04-27
```

[You can read more here](https://medium.com/@ggajos/jdk9-iterate-days-with-localdate-datesuntil-db5d73ec3545).